# adding padding to svg g element

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

my d3.js code generates the following HTML (this was taken from inspect element)

[image]

The paths render a circle with text at the bottom of it.

[image]

Ultimately I want the text to be UNDER the circle within the bounds of the SVG element. If the SVG element is larger, the G element renders larger. I need to control either the size of the G element or the size of the path elements.

How would I add width and height constraints or padding to the G element? It doesn't respond to `width`, `height`, `x`, `y` in style

cursory google search was not very helpful

thanks for any insight.

Comment: The `g` element doesn't really render at all, it's the `path` and `text` elements you need to adjust.

Comment: @robertc thanks this worked, add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<g>` element doesn't really render at all, it's the `<path>` and `<text>` elements you need to adjust.